# Cannot invoke LWC from Apex class

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, unmanaged-package

I'm using a scratch org and developing lwc.
LWC code :

```
  import createTransaction from '@salesforce/apex/MyClass.test';
        onButtonClick() {
         const msg = {
                   message: 'test'
                };
                this.test(msg);
            }
        test({ request: transaction })
                    .then(result => {
                        if(result.resultStatus === 'ERROR') {
                            this.showToast('error', 'error', result.message); 
                        }
                        else {
                            this.showToast('success', 'Success', result.message);
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        this.error = error;
                        this.dispatchShowErrorToastEvent(error.status + ': ' + error.statusText);
                    });
```

Apex code:

```
 public with sharing class MyClass{
        @AuraEnabled
        public static TransactionResult createTransaction(Request req) {
        System.Debug('req >> ' + req);

        return new TransactionResult();
    }

    public class Request{
       @AuraEnabled
       public string message;
    }
```

When I try to call, I receive error message in console:
400: Bad Request

There is no apex debug logs in dev console. Seems that my request doesn't pass to backend.

Answer (score 2):

2 things,

You have written method name as `createTransaction` in apex where as you are importing `test` method. You have to import proper method.

```
import createTransaction from '@salesforce/apex/MyClass.createTransaction';
```

Secondly, the parameter name in apex and in lwc should match. In Apex the variable name is `req` where in your js you have used `request` , thus it won't work

```
onButtonClick() {
    const msg = {
               message: 'test'
            };

        }
    createTransaction ({ req: transaction })
                .then(result => {
                    console.log('success')
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks.Updated my code, still have the same error

Comment: @DmitryProzorovskiy is your apex class even saving? there is no return statement in `createTransaction` method

Comment: Yes, it's saved. I posted a small piece of code. I updated my code above.

Comment: You have to fix your JS and Apex, with this many syntaxtic and logical  error it would hard for me to help. You have to remove all irrelevant code, and provide a minimum viable reproduction,.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a lot of errors in your code. Without changing your Apex at all, here's what your JavaScript should look like:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import createTransaction from '@salesforce/apex/MyClass.createTransaction';

export default class MyComponentName extends LightningElement {
    onButtonClick() {
     const msg = {
               message: 'test'
            };
            this.sendRequest(msg);;
        }
    sendRequest(transaction) {
        createTransaction({ req: transaction })
                .then(result => {
                    if(result.resultStatus === 'ERROR') {
                        this.showToast('error', 'error', result.message); 
                    }
                    else {
                        this.showToast('success', 'Success', result.message);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.error = error;
                    this.dispatchShowErrorToastEvent(error.status + ': ' + error.statusText);
                });
        }
    // rest of class here //
}
```